# unit test selection in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following situation.

I have a list of urls in the database. I need to fetch those urls and run my test cases in selenium grid.

But, the problem is I am not using any unit testing framework/library. Should I use python nose/unittest ?

Comment: Is your database MYSQL?

Comment: Please specfiy your needs more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

use unittest

```
import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
------------------------
------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

Comment: your code won't work in Python as you don't use whitespaces correctly.